# Scroll Position problem in nextjs after submitting form with javascript disabled

Tags: forms, next.js, server, action

I am using Nextjs to submit a form with server actions and javascript disabled. My form is in the very bottom of the page. When i submit the form, page reloads at top and i have to scroll to bottom to see form State.

```
<form
      className="contact__form"
      id="portfolio-contact-form"
      action={formAction}
    >
```